# Change SettingsPreferenceFragment header icon in Android

Tags: android, icons, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

i'm trying to change the header icons of a preference fragment without any luck. I tried setting it on Manifest and didn't work, also, i red something here on stackoverflow by calling Window. but it won't work also. Anyone got a solution?

[image]

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Test"
        android:exported="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_test"
        android:label="Test"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:excludeFromRecents="false"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

even if the preference screen shown and works good, the icon displayied on the header remain the stock settings icon :S

Comment: You need to show some code what's not working. I've just tried and for me it works..

Comment: how did you do that? i tried by setting it on amanifest but it doesn't work!... code added

Comment: Are you sure all your drawables are the correct icon? I've tried with your manifest settings and I have no problems changing my settings activity icon with another drawable or mipmap icon.